# Detect if click is on element stroke or fill

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

Is there any way to run one code-path when a user clicks the fill and another when the user clicks the stroke of a particular element? I know I could use pointer-events to limit clicks to one or the other, but is there a way to detect which was actually clicked?

**EDIT**

For future visitors to this question: This does not appear to be possible currently, but it has been suggested to the SVG WG for some such feature to be included in SVG2 http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/SVG2_Requirements_Input#Detect_if_a_mouse_event_is_on_the_fill_or_stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no provision in the svg spec to let you know which part was clicked no. I assume you'd want something like a property on the [MouseEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) interface saying which part was clicked. There's no existing property that can be reused for this purpose I think (event.detail might have been one possibility if it hadn't already been used).